# BIDS SSIS components greyed out in Toolbox

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, ssis

I a using Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio (SSIS) 2008. I can see components in my toolbox but they are greyed out. I cannot access them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a "show all" in the toolbox? If so, then you will see all controls that are possible to use, instead of the ones that are usable in our current context. The ones that are not usable in your context will be greyed out.

Where are you? designing SSIS and thus in control flow or data flow? or in SSRS or SSAS?

Cheers,

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

hi
have you installed visual studio properly??
Can you tell me what type of designer you have open?  (E.g. aspx, etc.)
try to change the profile name.